# Ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS freezes after 20 minutes of use

Tags: server, 20.04, suspend, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server and facing an unusual issue. Everything worked until recently. After routine reboot the server now works fine for only ~20 minutes and afterwards freezes. I am using an ssh connection to communicate with the server. Therefore after 20 mins I cannot establish ssh connection and the IP ping is unreachable. The server uses 5.4.0-72-generic kernel version. The last lines of /var/log/syslog indicate that system is suspending.

What could be the cause of the problem? I am willing to provide any needed information about system/hardware to diagnose the issue.

**Edit:**

To prevent system from suspending I've manually disabled sleep/suspend/hibernate using:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And verified changes with:

```
sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Now the issue seems to be resolved, however disabling suspend is bypassing the problem rather than providing solution.
Still, the last lines of /var/log/syslog show that there is an attempt (although blocked) to suspend the server.

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2738]: dbus-daemon[2738]: [session uid=122 pid=2738] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.5' (uid=122 pid=2877 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2738]: dbus-daemon[2738]: [session uid=122 pid=2738] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
gsd-power[3007]: Error calling suspend action: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
```

Comment: I'm having this issue too on my ODROID.  Seems to suspend plex and make it unresponsive.  Even causes it to stop streaming while watching something.  I haven't had any luck stopping it.

Comment: From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127740 try `dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing`.  Check the settings with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`